# Restarting web service

Tags: c#, windows, service

Question, I have a windows service running a task every one minute, It's connecting to a server and runs some kind of job on that server,but today i got an error from the server "WebException: The operation has timed out", the admin was changing some parameters so I got that error and my windows service couldn't connect any more on server, so when I restarted my service it connected momentarily.My question is it nececary to restart win service every time if that kind of error happens, I tout that win service would connect automatically without any kind of interaction from my side, or I have to write some kind of code to do that?

Comment: Probably would be helpful to post some sample code. If your service threw a WebException, that means that it was unhandled and caused the service to fail/close, I assume. You may just need to try/catch on your web service calls.

Comment: I have that, I search trough internet that it's mandatory to restart win service when changing parameters in let say web config, there is a workaround but it's to complicated.

Comment: Does that happen often? Generally speaking, you shouldn't have to worry about changing web.config files so frequently that you would have to worry about dynamically handling that situation.

Comment: No it doesn't happen often, the problem is that the win service couldn't connect to server because the admin change something, but after I restarted win service it connected in a mater of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle Exception u need to put TRY{}Catch in your code. And its always helpful to maintain log. Put log in every try catch and finally statement. Also please remember to close all Open connection in Finally statement.......